# Setup organization page that automatically links to content within repos

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

Fairly new to Jekyll, not really sure whether this is possible or the best way to go about it.

I am trying to setup an organization page that automatically includes content hosted in different repos. This way the organization page serves as an index of the *content* in the individual repos (not the repos themselves).

I haven't been able to find the documentation for this yet. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

---

Edit:

I don't think my question is being understood so I am revising it here.

I would like the org page to *aggregate* content from repositories.

Example:

Suppose I am a professor, run a research group, and have students working on  different projects. I setup separate repositories for each project so that students can blog about their progress for the project s/he is working on. I can use Jekyll so that anyone can go to `my_org.github.io/projectA` to read about project A, and `my_org.github.io/projectB` to read about project B, and so on. However I want someone to be able to go to `my_org.github.io/` and see blog posts from *all* projects.

So why not uses tags or something like that? Because suppose that I don't want students to have access to *all* of the repos – just the one for that project.

Whenever someone posts to `my_org.github.io/projectA` or `my_org.github.io/projectB` I want that content to also be listed at `my_org.github.io/`.

---

To be clear I don't want to index the repositories – I want to index the *content* of the repositories (i.e. the content of the `_posts` directory).

I don't mind if I have to refresh the organization page – I can just have a script do that once a day. However I don't want to have to also copy or move content into the organization page repo.

Answer (score 0):

Your main content in `userName.github.io` in the master branch. You can also point a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) on this repository.

Now you can create a project repository (ie: `myRepo`). This project can host code in the `master` branch and his documentation in the `gh-pages` branch.
The `gh-pages` branch generation result can now be reached a `userName.github.io/myRepo` or `customDomain/myRepo`.

You main menu in `userName.github.io` can now have link like `<a href="/myRepo">My super project</a>`.

Automatic !

Edit : After your edit.

Professor owns `github.com/professor` account. He creates a jekyll blog in the `professor.github.io` repository. This allows him to create repositories for students projects.

Professor creates a `github.com/professor/projectA` and allows `student1` and `student2` to contribute to it.

`student1` and `student2` can then commit (if needed) to projectA master branch for code and to `gh-pages` branch for documentation.

The only thing professor has to do is a link from professor.github.io to professor.github.io/projectA. Content is already in project repository and there is no need to replicate it on professor.github.io.

Maybe the only thing to do is using the same templates and style sheets.

If you really want to replicate content from project repositories in user repository, you will need to :

- create a Jekyll plugin that index all your project repositories and push content on the user repository
- install this Jekyll + plugin on a server
- setup a cron job that start a build each day and push the result on github

Not sure it's the simplest way to do it.

Comment: Won't this only link to the repo -- not to content in the repo?

Comment: The repository is at `github.com/userName/myRepo`, the web content at `userName.github.io/myRepo`.

Comment: I have tried to clarify my question to better reflect what it is I am trying to do.